# How to build with jenkins and deploy on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, deployment, amazon-ecs

I have the following task. I have a spring-boot app(backend), and a react app(frontend). I want to build the apps and deploy them on aws. I want to build them with Jenkins. What is the right way to do it? Should Jenkins be on a separate instance and deploy the apps on other instances? Should I use ECS? Using ECS with Jenkins seems like a complex task. The information online is confusing. If you have some guides that would be great.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/setup-jenkins-build-server/

Comment: I know this, but my task is far more complex. I did install Jenkins, but what is the right way to deploy. How to deploy each application on instances of their own.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to deploy to AWS : the easiest way to get started is to use aws developer tools

1. code commit - to store your source code. it is based on git
2. code build - to build and test your code.
3. code depoy - to deploy on ec2 instances or ECS, whatever you like
4. Code pipeline - to connect 1, 2 and 3 and it also allows you to choose Jenkins in place of code build.

https://aws.amazon.com/products/developer-tools/